# What does waiting/clock icon next to a message mean and what if I delete message in this state?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

When my device is not connected to any network (WiFi/Cellular data) and I send any message, I have seen a waiting/clock icon next to that message.

So what exactly does that mean? Is that message added to a queue for next batch process to inform server or something else?

And during that state (waiting/clock icon next to message) if I delete that message, will that deleted message still be delivered to the recipient?

Actually, I mistakenly sent a message to one of my contacts and luckily that time I was not connected to any network. After a few seconds when I realized this, I deleted that message. But I am not sure if it got deleted completely or it will get delivered when I reconnect to any network. I don't want that message to be delivered to the recipient, so I had disabled all networks on my device.

Comment: If not connected, it most likely stands for "scheduled", as you've assumed correctly. If deleted in that state, it should not be sent (how could it?).

Comment: @Izzy Yes even i think same. But not sure, how whatsapp devp had implemented.

Comment: That I can't tell either. I'm not even using Whatsapp :)

Answer (score 1):

The Clock icon means that you haven't sent the message yet. If you see a single tick mark it means that you have sent the message and it has been received by the WhatsApp server(but not the destined user)
If you see a double tick mark, that means the message has been received by the recipient too.

If a message has a single tick with it, it can't be stopped from getting to the user. But if you sent a message when offline and deleted when the phone was offline I don't think the message will reach its destination.

Comment: Yes, ideally message should not reach to recipient and get deleted completely. But not sure, how whatsapp devp had implemented.

Comment: After 10 or more minutes you should get a notification that replaces the +⏰ (Message Symbol with a Clock overlaid) with a red 'Triangle Exclamation Mark' and a sending failure message. Clicking on the Message gives the usual options but if you scroll down it will say "Retry Sending" (so you know it wasn't sent). Clicking on it also offer the option to delete. Different Phones may have different options than HTC.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience, if you send a message with no internet connectivity (clock sign appears), it shouldn't go to their server. If you delete it for everyone, it should immediately get deleted. But what happens after is if you now turn your net on, the message goes despite deleting it for everyone.